# Alternate between different data-types

Tags: c++, templates, vector

I'm trying to figure this out, and, it's really annoying me. I have a function that converts either an array or a vector into a vector of complex numbers, but, I do not know how it would be possible for the function to be able to accept both double arrays, as well as double vectors. I've tried using templates, but, this does not seem to work.template

```
template<typename T>
vector<Complex::complex> convertToComplex(T &vals)
{

}


Value::Value(vector<double> &vals, int N) {

};


Value::Value(double *vals, int N) {


};
```

What I am hoping for is this:

```
int main()
{
   double[] vals = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
   int foo = 4;
   Value v(vals, foo); // this would work and pass the array to the constructor, which would
                  // then pass the values to the function and covert this to a 
                  //   vector<complex>
}
```

I could do the same for a vector as well.. I don't know whether or not templates are the right approach for this.

Comment: Is that the actual code? You're only passing one argument to the constructor of `Value` when it takes two.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious My bad. This is just text code. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make your function and constructor a template that takes two iterators:

```
template<typename Iterator>
vector<Complex::complex> convertToComplex(Iterator begin, Iterator end)
{

}

class Value
{
 public:
  template <Iteraror>
  Value(Iterator begin, Iterator end)
  {
    vector<Complex::complex> vec = comvertToComplex(begin, end);
  }
  .... 
};
```

then

```
double[] vals = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
Value v(std::begin(vals), std::end(vals)); 

std::vector<double> vec{1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
Value v2(v.begin(), v.end());
```

I have omitted `foo` because it isn't very clear to me what its role is.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But, does `template <Iteraror>` exist?

Comment: @Phorce no, you have to write it, following what I have shown here.

Comment: @Phorce `Iterator` is just a template parameter. You could call it `Fred` if you wanted. Just look at some example function templates for inspiration.

Comment: Gotcha :)! Thanks so much man, much appreciated! More reading on iterators and templates for me.

Answer (score 2):

No need to define a template function here if you only want to support doubles.
You should do it like this, it's much simpler:

```
vector<Complex::complex> convertToComplex(const double* array, size_t len)
{
  // ... your implementation
}

vector<Complex::complex> convertToComplex(const vector<double>& v, size_t len)
{
  return convertToComplex(v.data(), len);
}
```

That's it!