# Pushing values into struct

Tags: c++, oop, templates, iterator

Apologies for the title, I was struggling to come up with one.

I asked a question on here [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17457529/alternate-between-different-data-types) and I'm trying to advanced with it. I have a struct:

```
namespace Complex {

typedef struct complex_t { 
    double re; 
    double im;
    } complex;
}
```

And I wish to push back either an `array` or a `vector` to a 1D vector of complex, as follows:

```
template<typename Iterator>
vector<Complex::complex> convertToComplex(Iterator begin, Iterator end)
{
     vector<Complex::complex> vals12(10);


     for(auto i=begin; (i != end); i++)
     {
      vals12[i].re = *i;
     }

     return vals12;
  }
```

And get the following error:

`no viable overloaded operator[] for type 'vector<Complex::complex>'
                vals12[i].re = *i;`

Now note if I do the following:

`vals12[0].re = 10;`

Will work, but, when using arrays it throws this error and I cannot understand why this is. My only thought is that it could be due to the fact I'm passing an `array` through rather than a vector. Here is the full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "complex.h"

using namespace std;
//using namespace Complex; 

template<typename Iterator>
vector<Complex::complex> convertToComplex(Iterator begin, Iterator end)
{
     vector<Complex::complex> vals12(10);


 for(auto i=begin; (i != end); i++)
 {
     vals12[i].re = *i;
 }

 return vals12;
 }

 class Value
 {
     public:
     template <typename Fred>
     Value(Fred begin, Fred end)
     {
          vector<Complex::complex> vec = convertToComplex(begin, end);
     }
  };

  int main()
  { 
  double vals[] = {10, 23, 23, 34, 354};
  Value v(std::begin(vals), std::end(vals));
  }
```

Does anyone have any ideas to where I am going wrong? I really hope someone can help me.

Update:

```
template<typename Iterator>
vector<Complex::complex> convertToComplex(Iterator begin, Iterator end)
{
vector<Complex::complex> vals12(10);

size_t index = 0;

for(auto i=begin; (i != end); i++)
{
    complex c;
    c.re = *i;
    c.im = *i;

    vals12[index].re = c.re;
    vals12[index].im = c.im;

    index++;
}

return vals12;
 }
```

Error:

`error: assigning to 'double *' from incompatible type 'double'; remove *
                c.re = *i;`

Comment: C++ is not C, you can say `struct complex { ... };` and lose the typedef

Comment: Which line of code gives the error in your update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you declare `i` as `auto` in the `for` initializer it takes on the type of `begin` which in this case is a pointer to `double`. You are then attempting to pass that pointer the index operator of `std::vector` (although indirectly via `[i]`).

You will need to use an additional variable to act as the index.

```
size_t index = 0;
for(auto i=begin; (i != end); i++)
{
    vals12[index++].re = *i;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Using this method, I get the following error: `assigning to 'double *' from incompatible type 'double'; remove * vals12[index++].re = *i;`

Comment: Using the code provided in your question and the example in my answer it compiles and runs fine.

Answer (score 2):

Other answers have explained why your code doesn't compile. You actually want a transform algorithm:

```
namespace Complex {
    struct complex_t { 
    double re; 
    double im;
  };
}
template<typename Iterator>
vector<Complex::complex_t> convertToComplex(Iterator begin, Iterator end)
{
     vector<Complex::complex_t> vals12;

     std::transform(begin, end, std::back_inserter(vals12), 
                   [](const double& d ){ return Complex::complex_t{d,0}; });

     return vals12;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that `i` is an `Iterator`. However, `operator[]` expects an `int` for the index into the `vector`. You have at least two solutions:

1. Create a counter for the index into the vector.
2. Create an empty vector and use `push_back()`.

Comment: Hey, I implemented the suggestions you made but got the error (please see my original post). Thank you for your help

Comment: `vector<Complex::complex> vals12(10);` makes a vector containing 10 default constructed elements. Contrary to what this answer says, the elements *are* available for use, and `vals12[0].re = *i;` is well defined.

Comment: @Mankarse grr that's what I get for switching languages back and forth (My original answer is the behavior of Java's `ArrayList`.)...thanks for the correction.